# How to load a custom dialog box on a radiobutton onchange() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a onchange event on several radiobuttons that calls a function  called dialogPopUp(). Currently this function displays an alert box which works fine. However I want this function to display a dialog box. I have tried several solutions but nothing seems to work. I want the dialog box to popup, not open a new window, which the *window.open* does.

Here's an example of a page with radiobuttons:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>1. Har jag klart för mig vad uppdraget innebär?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
        <label for="radio-choice-1">Ja</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="radio2" value="choice-2"  onchange="dialogPopUp()" /> 
        <label for="radio2">Nej</label>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn">Nästa fråga</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
<script>
function dialogPopUp(){
    alert("asd");
}
</script>
```

Here's the dialog box that I want to load by using the previous method:

```
 <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="dialog1">
 <div data-role="header">
 <h1>Riskbedömning</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 <form>
    <label for="danger">Fara:</label><input type="text" name="danger" id="danger"/>
            <label for="risc">Gradera risk:</label><select name="risc" id="risc">
                <option value="L">Låg</option>
                <option value="M">Medel</option>
                <option value="H">Hög</option>
            </select>
    <label for="measure">Förebyggande åtgärd:</label><input type="text" name="measure" id="measure"/>
    <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn">Nästa fråga</a>
    </form>
     </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text In Dialog</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: jquery-mobile? jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery...it is possible

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
   $('#dialog1').hide();
     $('#rbt').onChange(function (){
          $('#dialog1').show();
       });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your dialog box is already hidden. If not this code will hide it

```
$("#dialog1").fadeOut(0);
```

Add Jquery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//This will hide the dialog
$("#dialog1").fadeOut(0);

//This will show your Dialog

$("#radio2").click(function(){
$("#dialog1").fadeOut(100);
});


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you've to disable the dialog div using `display: none`.

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="dialog1" style="display:none">
```

Now just use [.dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) method of jQuery for that div

```
$("#dialog1").dialog();
```

That it and you're done !

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPXj5/)

**UPDATE**:

Well jQuery mobile check for `data-rel="dialog"` attribute on the tag and shows a dialog box if it is present. If we add that dialog it is showing up as a dialog. You can also check the official [jquery documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/).

> Any page can be presented as a modal dialog by adding the data-rel="dialog" attribute to the page anchor link. When the "dialog" attribute is applied, the framework adds styles to add rounded corners, margins around the page and a dark background to make the "dialog" appear to be suspended above the page.

Check the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPXj5/1/). Although I didnot set the overlay and other stuff but it still works

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. I forgot to mention that I use JQuery Mobile. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Be weary of popups.  Many browsers are stopping them these days.  Rather use a DIV that you can simply hide/show in the centre (or where you need it to be) and it will anyway be modal "basically" (stop the user from seeing the page content - behind it.)